# Apache VFS FileChanged not fired with existing files on a directory

Tags: java, apache, vfs, file-monitoring

Im trying to watch over a directory using Apache VFS DefaultFileMonitor but if the files already exist, it's not fire the FileChangedEvent, it fires just if a create a new file and change it.
I tried with this example from the documentation but no luck.

```
FileSystemManager manager = VFS.getManager();
FileObject dir= manager.resolveFile("/home/user/temp");
DefaultFileMonitor fm = new DefaultFileMonitor(new MyListener());
fm.setDelay(5000);
fm.addFile(dir); 
fm.start();
```

This is supposed to watch a diretory and notify file changes, but it's not happening.
Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was using org.apache.commons.vfs.* and this package really does not support that feature.
So when i dig a little more i found that they have another version, org.apache.commons.vfs2.*
and now it's working.